# Netezza Sql query

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a list of tables in a Netezza database and I want to get the name of primary key for each of the tables.

Can anyone provide me the query.

Comment: I'm having a hell of a time finding any documentation for Netezza, but I'd probably start by looking at the system views.  `select * from _v_table;` for example

Comment: Thanks Abe ! I will look at the system views.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT * FROM _v_relation_keydata;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing sort of Primary Key thing in Netezza. If you want to look at the NULL or NOT NULL constraints for your required table you can enter the below commands from your nzsql command line

\d [YOURTABLENAME]

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT database
        , schema
        , constraintname
        , relation as tablename
        , conseq as seq
        , attname as columnname, *
FROM _v_relation_keydata
where contype='p'
and schema='ADMIN'
order by relation, conseq
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't much useful.

Comment: True in general, but it certainly was for me this time! :)

Answer (score 0):

We do not have `primary key` concept in `Netezza`. If you are concerned about `Not NULL` columns following query will help you.

```
select * from _v_relation_column where NAME='TABLE_NAME' and ATTNOTNULL='Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

The key(primary/foreign) concepts is not there in Netezza. But we can create primary keys in Netezza and this is created to sync the model with the outside data reporting tools like Informatica/Microstrategy.

You can look into the system view _v_relation_keydata.