# Using UNIX SAS to ascertain Netezza DISTRIBUTE_ON key

Tags: sas, netezza

Is anybody able to provide some SAS 9.1.3 code for ascertaining the DISTRIBUTE_ON key of a particular Netezza table?

have tried using the guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722478/netezza-sql-query) but the table comes back empty..

Answer (score 0):

There is a nzsql command called \d  which will retrieve the  distribution keys on the table. Check the NZ Database User Guide.

Regards,
Venk

Comment: Yes but can you submit these commands (and view the results) using SAS?